# Set default value on a custom property

Tags: c#, episerver

I have created a longstring custom property that gives me a XHTML editor. So far so good but I need help with two things.

First, I would like to fill the property with a default value. I've looked at a couple of blog post about this but can't seem to get it right.

Second, I would want to render the custom property as a regular `textbox` that can hold a large string.

```
public class CustomerTypeBoxControl :
    EPiServer.Web.PropertyControls.PropertyLongStringControl
{
    protected override void SetupEditControls()
    {
        base.SetupEditControls();                            
    }

    public CustomerTypeBox CustomerTypeBox
    {
        get
        {
            return PropertyData as CustomerTypeBox;
        }
    }
}

[Serializable]
[PageDefinitionTypePlugIn]
public class CustomerTypeBox : EPiServer.Core.PropertyLongString
{
    public override IPropertyControl CreatePropertyControl()
    {
        return new CustomerTypeBoxControl();
    }
}
```

Comment: When you add the property to the page, does it give you the options to disable all the rich editor abilities like bold and italic? If you turn them all off, you simply have a long string editor.

Comment: Can you just use a page builder type?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if it is steel relevant but here is the solution:

```
TextBox _textBox;
protected override void SetupEditControls()
{
    base.SetupEditControls();

    _textBox = (TextBox)EditControl;
    var value = CustomerTypeBox.Value ?? string.Empty;
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(value.ToString()))
    {
        _textBox.Text = "Default text";
    }
    else
    {
        _textBox.Text = value.ToString();
    }
    if (_textBox != null) EditControl.Parent.Controls.Add(_textBox);
}

public override void ApplyEditChanges()
{
    var customerTypeBoxValue = _textBox.Text;

    if (customerTypeBoxValue != null)
    {
        SetValue(customerTypeBoxValue);
    }
}
```

Default value for property is also possible to set in admin mode.